# PhoneGap Email Plugin

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to use the plugin [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/EmailComposerWithAttachments) This is the first time I have started to use Phonegap in Android, so the process is a little unfamiliar to me.

So far I have added the `.JAVA` file to here "src.org.apache.cordova" I have added the `.JS` to the www folder and have referenced it in my `HTML` file.

I have added the following to my `config.xml`

```
<plugin name="EmailComposer" value="org.apache.cordova.emailComposer"/>
```

As the README file does not really go into specifics, I am assuming this is the value that must go in here.

I then use the following in my `HTML` file.

```
window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(null,"Look at this photo","Take a look at <b>this<b/>:",["example@email.com", "johndoe@email.org"],[],[],true,["_complete_path/image.jpg", "_other_complete_path/file.zip"]);
```

This is straight from the README file, nothing happens when I run the application. Not even an error.

I have tried using various versions in the emulator and on a Samsung S2 running 4.0.3

Phonegap version 2.7

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: @Girl_engineer Could you brief what excatly is your issue? As the plugin link in the question itself is not accessible?

Comment: This was a number of years ago so much of it all will have changed

Comment: @Girl_engineer Any update on what you are exactly look for in this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The mail plugin from katzer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer) works like a charm.

Use `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-email-composer@0.8.3` to add install it locally.

If you are using **PhoneGap Build**, don't forget to add the following line to the config.xml

`<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" version="0.8.3" source="npm" />`

Answer (score 1):

This was simply down to case sensitive values - I changed the following

```
org.apache.cordova.emailComposer
```

For

```
org.apache.cordova.EmailComposer
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this plugin its easy to use with more features available.

latest stable version - cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-email-composer@0.8.3

https://github.com/AppGyver/email-composer/

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

Comment: You should add some more info about the plugin and why he "needs" to use it.

Comment: You can achieve multiple things by using these plugins like - email send , save draft , send attachments ( many type like img , file etc.. ) also it supports multi platform and easy to use and integrate through command line. For  more info try to open plugins link and try to use.